# How to specify make program in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Vim has makeprg variable. This variable takes program name which will be executed if :make is entered. Is there something similar in emacs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `make` command in Emacs, but there is `compile`:

> ```
> Compile the program including the current buffer.  Default: run `make'.
> Runs COMMAND, a shell command, in a separate process asynchronously
> with output going to the buffer `*compilation*'.
> ```

The command that gets run by `compile` is defined by the variable `compile-command`, which can be set like this:

```
(setq compile-command "some command")
```

`compile-command`'s default value is `"make -k "`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable [`compile-command`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand) specifies the compiler program, which you can customize as needed.  Here's the manual page for [`M-x compile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) and family.